# When I read from a file in C++ it, displays the numbers more times then it should

Tags: c++, ios, arrays, file-io

I am coding a program that allows the user to name a file and open or create that file. Then they are able to read the info from that file in different ways or write more info into the file. The problem is that when I choose an option to read the file it first reads it fine then when I try to read it a different way it has two sets of numbers, as if it is reading the file twice.

I am unable to pin point the problem to any one function, and it is hard the explain the problem so I am posting the whole program. if you could help that would be great. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(), f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), f5(), f6(), f7();
string file;
const int NUM_DATA = 50;
double data[NUM_DATA], temp;
int num = 0;

int main()
{
    int choice;
    do
    {
        system ("cls");
        cout << " ** MENU ** \n\n";
        cout << "Current Data File: " << file << "\n\n";
        cout << "(1) Select/Create data file (.txt file extension will be added           automatically)\n";
        cout << "(2) Display all the numbers, total and average\n";
        cout << "(3) Display all the numbers from smallest to the largest\n";
        cout << "(4) Select a number and display how many times it shows up\n";
        cout << "(5) Display the largest number\n";
        cout << "(6) Append random number(s)\n";
        cout << "(7) Exit the program\n\n";

        do 
        {
            cout << "Choice: ";
            cin >> choice;
            cout << endl;
        } 
        while (choice < 1 || choice > 7);


        switch (choice)
        { 
           case 1: f1();
              break;
           case 2: f2();
              break;
           case 3: f3();
              break;
           case 4: f4();
              break;
           case 5: f5();
              break;
           case 6: f6();
              break;
       }
   }
   while (choice != 7);

   return 0;
}
// Select file
int f1()
{
   cout << "Name of data file: ";
   cin >> file;
   file = file + ".txt";
   ifstream fileI;
   fileI.open(file.c_str());

   if(!fileI)
   {
       cout << "\nFile not found, creating file. \n\n";
       ofstream fileO;
       fileO.open(file.c_str());
       fileO.close();
   }
   else
   {
       cout << "\nFile successfully read. \n\n";
       fileI.close();
   }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
// Display all the numbers, the total and the average
int f2()
{
   f7();
   ifstream fileI;
   fileI.open(file);
   double total = 0;
   double average;

    for (int count = 0; count < num; count++)
    {
        total += data[count];
        cout << data[count] << endl;
    }
    average = total / num;
    cout << "Total: " << total << endl;
    cout << "Avearage: " << average << "\n\n";

    fileI.close();

    system("pause");
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
// Display all the numbers from smallest to largest
int f3()
{
    f7();
   ifstream fileI;
   fileI.open(file);
   for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
       {
           for(int j = 0; j < num; j++)
           {
               if(data[i] < data[j])
               {
                   int temp = data[i];
                   data[i] = data[j];
                   data[j] = temp;
               } 
           }
       }

for (int count = 0; count < num; count++)
{
        cout << data[count] << "\n\n";
}
fileI.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
// Display how many times a number shows up
int f4()
{
   f7();
   ifstream fileI;
   fileI.open(file);
   int numb, times = 0;

   cout << "Search number: ";
   cin >> numb;
   cout << endl;

   for (int count = 0; count < num; count++) 
   {
        if (numb == data[count])
        {   
           times ++;
        }
   }
   cout << numb << " ocurrs " << times << " times." << "\n\n";
   fileI.close();
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
// Display the largest number
int f5()
{
   f7();
   ifstream fileI;
   fileI.open(file);
   int large = data[0];
   for (int count = 0; count < num; count++)
   {
       if (large < data[count])
       {
            large = data[count];
       }
   }
   cout << "Larget number: " << large << "\n\n";
   fileI.close();
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
// Append one or more random numbers
int f6()
{
   ofstream fileO;
   fileO.open(file, ios::app);
   int rndm, numbs;
   srand(time(NULL));
   cout << "Add how many numbers: ";
   cin >> rndm;
   cout << endl;

   for (int count = num + 1; count <= num + rndm ; count++)
   {
        numbs = (rand()%50+1);
        fileO << numbs << endl;
   }
   cout << "Data succesfully written.\n\n";
   fileO.close();
   system("pause");
   return 0;
  }
//Array function
int f7()
{
   ifstream fileI;
   fileI.open(file);
   fileI >> temp;


   while (num < NUM_DATA && !fileI.eof())
   {
       data[num] = temp;
       ++num;
       fileI >> temp;
   }
   fileI.close();
   return num;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because, in `f7()`, you use `num` from it's last known value, rather than resetting it.

That means you're simply tacking another copy of the file on to the end of the array each time.

And, please, if you value the sanity of the people who may have to maintain your code, *don't* use function names like `fN()`, they're supposed to be *readable* :-)

---

Interestingly enough, this only affects the functions that use the array. I notice that your function which gives you the total and average reads the file itself, despite calling `f7()` to read it into the array. You may want to choose *one* method and stick with it.